# How is a variable in a lambda expression given its value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods, generic-method

How does `index` in the below example obtain its value?  I understand that n is automatically obtained from the source `numbers`, but, while the meaning is clear, I do not see how index is given its value:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
var firstSmallNumbers = numbers.TakeWhile((n, index) => n >= index);
```

The signature of `TakeWhile` is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
```

Comment: Are you asking how it works out being well-typed, or what's the meaning of index/how `TakeWhile` is defined?

Comment: @delnan:  I thought I was asking a general question about lambdas, but based on the responses, I was really asking a question about how TakeWhile is using the lambda.  I understand that the type of n can be inferred from the type of the members of numbers, and the type of index is defined by Func<TSource, int, bool>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version of TakeWhile supplies the index of the source element in the sequence as the second parameter to the predicate. I.e. the predicate is called as predicate(5, 0), then predicate(4, 1), predicate(1, 2), predicate(3, 3) etc. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775.aspx).

There is also a “simpler” version of the function, supplying only the values in the sequence, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx).

Comment: Thanks .. it occurred to me after posting my question that TakeWhile must provide the value to index .. I am just getting used to parsing out inferred values from supplied values, and lambda usage in general.

Answer (score 2):

The index is generated by the implementation of `TakeWhile`, which might look a bit like [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Things become clear as long as you figure out how TakeWhile can be implemented :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item, index))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            yield break;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```